# FirebirdSql Service unable to start on Fedora Core 10

Tags: installation, fedora

I am trying to install the latest Firebird SS package on Fedora Core 10. I successfully upgraded to the latest FC kernel version (2.6.27.29-170) using Yum, and during the process it upgraded Firebird to version 2.1. However when starting the Firebird service I get the following error message:

> Starting Firebird server [default] /usr/lib64/firebird/bin/fbmgr.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfbclient.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>                                                              [FAILED]

I have searched for the relevant library and can't find it anywhere on the system.

Firebird used to work fine on the system until the upgrade, and I am unsure as to how to downgrade to the older version or even get the current version working. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have also done a Yum remove, deleted all Firebird directories and files I could find and reinstalled using Yum with no success. Google has also not been very helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to have occurred as a fluke.

After completely uninstalling the Firebird Super Server using yum with the following command

> yum remove firebird*

and removing all the directories related to Firebird:

> find / -name firebird*
>   rm -rf [firebird directory name]

and then reinstalling using

> yum install firebird*

Seems to have fixed the problem the second time around.